# Symfony Error: You have requested a non-existent parameter "file_path"

Tags: php, symfony

This is my stack trash, I am getting this when doing the existing Symfony project.

stack trash :
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "file_path". in D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\fashion\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php:102 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\fashion\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\EnvPlaceholderParameterBag.php(57): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag->get('file_path') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\fashion\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php(219): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\EnvPlaceholderParameterBag->get('file_path') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\fashion\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php(189): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag->resolveString('%file_path%', Array) #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboar in D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\fashion\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php on line 102

Comment: you try to use a parameter that does not exist  inside your service .yml probably !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling a parameter named `file_path` that is not registered in the container.

If you did register it, then clear the cache with `bin/console cache:clear`.

Also, don't use XAMPP: It get's too much in the middle. You can use Symfony's web server or php built-in web server. `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t /path/to/your/project`

Comment: remove file_path param from config.php